# Cakephp 3 SOAPclient

Tags: php, cakephp

I got this Script running in PHP and want to turn it in **Cakephp 3** with the Http Client

```
$strAPIKey = XXXXXXXXXXXX;
$client = new soapclient($url);
$arrResult = array();
$arrFilter[] = array('field'=>'id', 'operator'=>'bigger', 'value'=>20);
$arrSort = array('field'=>'customer', 'direction'=>'asc');
$arrResult = $client->getCustomers($strAPIKey, $arrFilter,$arrSort,10,0);
```

Is it possible with the **Cakephp 3** Http Client?

Answer (score 2):

The built in CakePHP 3 Http client is meant for restful/pure http servers. You can technically use it for soap, but you will need to build the entire soap envelope yourself. The PHP soapclient class is probably the best thing available for interfacing with soap.

So, in short, "No", rather carry on using what you are using.